# Select by category and count by status mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

I have a list of records and want to group by **categories** and after this count buy **isArchived** status.

I'm just starting to learn MongoDB and I can't do the query described below, I would appreciate your tips.

This is peace of data.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "63356af2d77a56d764f362e4",
        "noteName": "string",
        "category": "IDEA",
        "content": "string",
        "isArchived": true,
        "createdAt": "2022-09-29T09:52:50.477Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-29T09:52:50.477Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    
    {
        "_id": "63356afad77a56d764f362ea",
        "noteName": "string",
        "category": "IDEA",
        "content": "string",
        "isArchived": false,
        "createdAt": "2022-09-29T09:52:58.765Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-29T09:52:58.765Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "63356afbd77a56d764f362ee",
        "noteName": "string",
        "category": "IDEA",
        "content": "string",
        "isArchived": false,
        "createdAt": "2022-09-29T09:52:59.180Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-29T09:52:59.180Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "63356b04d77a56d764f362f4",
        "noteName": "string",
        "category": "TASK",
        "content": "string",
        "isArchived": false,
        "createdAt": "2022-09-29T09:53:08.261Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-29T09:53:08.261Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "63356b09d77a56d764f362fc",
        "noteName": "string",
        "category": "TASK",
        "content": "string",
        "isArchived": true,
        "createdAt": "2022-09-29T09:53:13.980Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-29T09:53:13.980Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "63356b0ad77a56d764f362fe",
        "noteName": "string",
        "category": "TASK",
        "content": "string",
        "isArchived": true,
        "createdAt": "2022-09-29T09:53:14.445Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-29T09:53:14.445Z",
        "__v": 0
    }]
```

**This is request**

```
getStats() {
    const stats = this.noteModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              category: '$category',
              isArchived: '$isArchived',
            },
            count: {
              $sum: 1,
            },
          },
        },
        { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
      ])
      .project({
        _id: 0,
        category: '$_id.category',
        isArchived: '$_id.isArchived',
        average: 1,
        count: '$count',
      });

    return stats;
  }
```

**Now I receive like this**

```
[
    {
        "category": "IDEA",
        "isArchived": false,
        "count": 5
    },
    {
        "category": "IDEA",
        "isArchived": true,
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "category": "QUOTE",
        "isArchived": false,
        "count": 4
    },
    {
        "category": "QUOTE",
        "isArchived": true,
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "category": "RANDOM THOUGHT",
        "isArchived": false,
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "category": "RANDOM THOUGHT",
        "isArchived": true,
        "count": 3
    }....
]
```

**But I want to receive it like this**

```
[
    {
        "category": "IDEA",
        "archived": 5,
        "unArchived": 3
    },
    {
        "category": "QUOTE",
        "archived": 5,
        "unArchived": 3
    },
    {
        "category": "RANDOM THOUGHT",
        "archived": 2,
        "unArchived": 3
    },
    {
        "category": "TASK",
        "archived": 3,
        "unArchived": 3
    },
]
```

**What should be changed in the query to get the required view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `category` only and calculate the `archived` and `unArchived` counts by checking the condition,

- archived condition is if `isArchived` is true then return 1 otherwise 0
- unArchived condition is if `isArchived` is true then return 0 otherwise 1

```
const stats = this.noteModel.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$category",
      archived: {
        $sum: { $cond: ["$isArchived", 1, 0] }
      },
      unArchived: {
        $sum: { $cond: ["$isArchived", 0, 1] }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yk09bgsZ1cj)